# Python Metaclass conflicts

Tags: python

I've tried to find a solution to this and can't really make head or tail of the answers I'm finding on here or through Google, so...

Here is a minimal piece of code

```
File test.py:
    import One

File One.py:
    from tkinter import ttk
    class One():
        pass

    class Two(One, ttk.Entry):
        pass
```

This works fine, as expected - but, if I now separate out class One and class Two into their own files and modify test to import Two:

```
File test.py:
    import Two

File One.py:
    class One():
        pass

File Two.py:
    from tkinter import ttk
    import One
    class Two(One, ttk.Entry):
        pass
```

I get the 'TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases' error.

I cannot see what I'm doing wring here.

For reference - Python 3.9.7 on Lubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Two` should inherit from `One.One` in the second configuration. Not from `One`.

Something equivalent you can do (still in the second configuration) is `from One import One` instead of `import One`.

Comment: ...and the OP demonstrated why clearer naming approaches is preferable.